# Excel Function or VBA needed to Sum Values of Rows with Identical Part Numbers

Tags: excel, vba

Need help, I have a huge sheet with manufacturer, part number, quantities, and some other information give. I think I'm looking for a VBA script that will produce a new row with sums of rows with identical part numbers. So in a "Totals" table I want the first row to show but to show with a quantity of 10, combining rows 1 and 5. Is this easier to do in a pivot table? I assumed this wouldn't be too bad to do in VBA but I'm lost. In the information given below, each group is it's own column, so Dell is A, Computer is in D. Thanks!

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dell | 54551AJDJF6 | 3 | Computer | Electrical | $52.30 | Robert | 4/12/2019 | 5/5/2020 | PO125 |
| Dell | 2664664HG7 | 8 | Computer Screen | Electrical | $142.00 | Robert | 4/12/2019 | 5/5/2020 | PO125 |
| Dell | 165165DFF7 | 4 | Keyboard | Electrical | $52.17 | Robert | 4/12/2019 | 5/5/2020 | PO125 |
| Dell | 2664664HG7 | 1 | Computer Screen | Electrical | $12.68 | Robert | 4/12/2019 | 5/5/2020 | PO125 |
| Dell | 54551AJDJF6 | 7 | Computer | Electrical | $23.21 | Robert | 4/12/2019 | 5/5/2020 | PO125 |

Comment: Yes, usually a Pivot Table is best for this - just try it. Advantage is that the pivot is always reflecting your actual data while a script needs to rerun every time you change your data. For VBA: Create a list of unique part numbers (using the remove duplicate function), then either loop over all part numbers and calculate the value using WorksheetFunction.SumIf or add a formula next to the part number that uses SumIf

Comment: @FunThomas Actually a Pivot Table is NOT dynamic. It must be manually refreshed in order to reflect source data changes. But this Pivot Table update CAN be initiated from VBA.

Answer (score 0):

easy way is to insert a column "Total QTY" in the table with this formula showing each PartNumber sum of quantity in the whole table.

```
=SUMIF([PartNumer],[@PartNumer],[QTY])
```

Comment: that would be very useful if it didn't constantly change with new part numbers coming in, was trying to figure out a way to use a formula like that but where the "partnumer" is just something saying if the values are the same, sum them here.

Comment: no doubt that it is not a clean way, but since the column is the part of the table that you have it constantly updating, this info in front of each part-number at its row shows the total balance of quantity. Another way would be using a separate list with dynamic unique value of Part-number like the one here ; https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4032-excel-dynamic-list-of-unique-values.html    and then use a sumif on that list.